# Scheduler algorithms and scheduler policy

Tags: operating-system, scheduler

In linux operating system, what is the difference between **"scheduler algorithms"** and **"scheduler policy"**?

Comment: Seems like the algorithms implement policy, which is an abstract set of rules used to define the OS's behavior. Can you provide a little more context and motivation? What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man 7 sched`:

> The scheduler is the kernel component that decides which runnable
>          thread will be executed by the CPU next.  Each thread has an
>          associated scheduling policy and a **static** scheduling priority,
>          sched_priority.  The scheduler makes its decisions based on knowledge
>          of the **scheduling policy** and static priority of all threads on the
>          system.

So, in the case of scheduling on Linux, the *scheduling algorithm* schedules processes. It's simply the algorithm that solves that specific problem. Every thread has a *scheduling policy*, which determines how it is scheduled. Again from `man 7 sched`:

> A  thread's scheduling policy determines where it will be inserted into
>   the list of threads with equal static priority and  how  it  will  move
>   inside this list.

Conclusion: the scheduling algorithm schedules according to one or more scheduling policies.